# How to parse URL segment Identifiers in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, octobercms

I'm using OctoberCMS based on Laravel.

I'm trying to capture segments of the URL to pass into a Scope Function to filter Database Results.

Visiting localhost/user/john/nature would parse and filter back those results.

URL → Identifiers → Param Variables → Scope → Database Results

[Routing Parameters](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components#routing-parameters)

[Query Scopes](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#query-scopes)

**Page**

```
[builderDetails builderUser]
identifierValue "{{ :username }}"

[builderDetails builderCategory]
identifierValue "{{ :category }}"

[builderList]
scope = "scopeApplyType"

url = /user/:username?/:category?/:page?
```

**Model Scope**

I want to filter Database Results using URL Identifers :username and :category.

```
public function scopeApplyType($query) {
    $params = ['username' => $username, 'category' => $category];
    return $query->where($params);
}
```

**Get Identifiers**

This will output the requested identifers in the URL, in routes.php

```
Route::get('user/{username?}/{category?}', function ($username = null, $category = null) {
    echo $username;
    echo $category;
});
```

Output

```
localhost/user/john/nature

john
nature
```

**Soultion?**

A Route::get() won't work, I need something inside or passed to the Scope to define the params variables.

Something like:

```
$username = '{username?}'; 
$username = request()->url('username');
$username = $this->param('username'); //Components)
$username = $this->route('username');
$username = \Route::current()->getParameter('username');
```

All return null or error.

Like the way you would normally parse a Query

```
$param = "username=john&category=nature";
$username = $category = ''; 
parse_str($param);
echo $username;
echo $category;
```

Or similar to Request Segment

```
$username = request()->segment(2); //user/:username
```

segment(2) is a static location unlike {:category} which can change position on different URL's.

Comment: Have you tried `$request->route('parameter_name')` or `$request->route()->parameters()`?

Comment: @BenSwinburne I get Undefined variable: request

Comment: You'd need to get the request object `request()` should give you it. `request()->route()`

Comment: @BenSwinburne $request is now defined but the parameters return null. https://i.imgur.com/J9vB5TW.png

Comment: @BenSwinburne My mistake, it is still not defined. Code placement was wrong.

Comment: I mean you need to define the var. `$request = request(); $request->route()->parameters()` or you can use `request()->route()->parameters()` etc

Comment: @BenSwinburne Here are what each output. It seems route() only contains 'slug', even though :slug is not set on my page. The last one $this->param() can't be used in the Model, only page. https://i.imgur.com/A0Pwmtx.png

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do has gone beyond the scope of the very basic components provided by the [builder plugin](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder).

You should now look at creating your own Components within your plugin. See http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components and http://octobercms.com/docs/cms/components for further information, as well as the [section on routing parameters specifically](http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components#routing-parameters)

A very basic example of your custom component might look like this:

```
<?php namespace MyVendor/MyPlugin/Components;

use Cms\Classes\ComponentBase;
use MyVendor\MyPlugin\Models\Result as ResultModel;

class MyComponent extends ComponentBase
{
    public $results;

    public function defineProperties()
    {
        return [
            'categorySlug' => [
            'title' => 'Category Slug',
            'type' => 'string',
            'default' => '{{ :category }}',
            ],
            'username' => [
                'title' => 'Username',
                'type' => 'string',
                'default' => '{{ :username }}',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $this->results = $this->page['results'] = $this->loadResults();
    }

    public function loadResults()
    {
        return ResultModel::where('username', $this->property('username'))
                      ->where('category', $this->property('categorySlug'))
                      ->get();
    }
}
```

Then in your component's default.htm view you'd do something like this:

```
{% for result in __SELF__.results %}
    {{ result.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

And in your OctoberCMS page:

```
url = /user/:username?/:category?/:page?

[myComponent]
categorySlug = "{{ :category }}"
username = "{{ :username }}"
==
{% component 'myComponent' %}
```

Comment: https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#query-scopes Here under Dynamic Scopes it shows how to applyType, but it doesn't work. I put it in my Page htm php, and directed it at my custom Component. $user = Gallery::applyType('john')->get(); It says "Call to undefined method October\Rain\Database\QueryBuilder::applyType()".

Comment: I will try your solution and add your code to my component.

Comment: @MattMcManis how did you write your scope method in your model? It needs to be defined in the form of public function scopeApplyType($query, $type)

Comment: You've got me very close to solving this, here is an extension to the question showing the scope. http://stackoverflow.com/q/42337725/6806643

Answer (score 0):

Given the following route

```
Route::get('foo/{name?}', function ($name = null) {
    dd(request()->route()->parameters());
});
```

When visiting /foo/bar the output is as below.

```
array:1 [▼
  "name" => "bar"
]
```

Similarly you can use

```
dd(request()->route()->parameter('name')); // bar
```

Comment: I used OctoberCMS to create the Page. When I use Route::get() in routes.php, it overrides my Page with a blank one. I used the dd() with 'username' and it returned a blank page with the word 'null'. But 'slug' returned 'user/john', the whole uri.

Comment: I can get the Identifier {username?} with $username = $this->param('username') only when used in the Page php, but how to use that same code in the Model or send to the Scope?

Comment: What does `$this` refer to? the above way is the Laravel 5 way to do it so it should work. What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: If I echo $this in the Page php, it returns "Object of class Cms58a1e3092320e853718389_1418827154Class could not be converted to string". It must be some sort of Page Class October is creating?

Comment: Presumably, yes. I'm not familiar with OctoberCMS but i'd have assumed that the standard Laravel stuff would work

Comment: Route::get() works and gets the identifiers, but it creates a new blank page over my existing one. Is there a way to use Route::put() to use on the existing page?

Comment: Use whatever routes you want. My example was simply to demonstrate how to use it inside a route. You can use the code I gave you almost anywhere in your application. I dare say you can probably use it in the query scope directly.

Comment: But how to make Route::get() avoid overwriting my existing page, giving me a blank one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135617/discussion-between-ben-swinburne-and-matt-mcmanis).