# Pass Variable from Component to Model Scope

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, octobercms

I'm using OctoberCMS based on Laravel.

I'm trying to get the identifier from URL and pass it to the Scope to filter database results.

$this->property('username') works and returns the username from the URL.

But how do you pass it to the Model and into the Scope function?

Here is the guide, under Dynamic Scopes.

https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#query-scopes

**Page**

URL: localhost/user/matt

Identifier: /user/:username

**Results Component**

```
public function init()
{
    // get username from url
    $username = $this->property('username'); //matt

    // pass username to scope
    Gallery::applyUser($username);
}
```

**Gallery Model**

```
// return results that match username
public function scopeApplyUser($query, $username)
{
    return $query->where('username', $username);
}
```

**Error**

```
Missing argument 2 for MyVendor\Gallery\Models\Gallery::scopeApplyUser()
```

**Solution?**

I found adding ($query, $username = null) allows the variable to pass without error.

But now the problem is that $username is both 'matt' and null at the same time and never makes it to the query return.

```
// return results that match username
public function scopeApplyUser($query, $username = null)
{
    print $username; //prints matt
    if ($username == null) { print 'null'; } //prints null

    return $query->where('username', $username); //returns null
}
```

[image: diagram]

Comment: Try to get property from url using as below $username = $_GET['username']; instead of $username = $this->property('username'); you will come to know really property can be accessed.

Comment: Side note: Also try using `Input::get("url_param")`

Comment: @Meysam It returned null.

Answer (score 1):

In a model gallery you need a field user:

```
class Gallery extends Model {
    /** these are just placeholder variables you should be recognising these from your own model.!**/
    protected $table = 'gallery';
    protected $guarded = ['*'];
    protected $fillable = ['username'];// Make sure this also is in the database!!
    public scopeWhereUser($query, $user = null) {
        if(!is_null($user)) { // Only do something if the username is provided!
           $query->where('username',$user);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when you have the nullchecks you can just call it with

```
 $gallery = new Gallery();
 $query = $gallery->newQuery()->where('x','y')->whereUser('matt');
```

Changes I made:

- renamed scope to whereuser instead of apply user because it's more logical to name it that way. Apply you do to something functional that changes a state permanently
- added a not is_null() check to only limit the query when it's not null.

full working example that prints the results:

```
 $gallery = new Gallery();
 $query = $gallery->newQuery()->where('x','y')->whereUser('matt');
 $results = $query->get();
 foreach($results as $galleryItem) {
     echo $galleryItem->getKey() . ' is having:<BR/>';
     echo dump([
               'model'=>$galleryItem,
               'methods' => get_class_methods(get_class($galleryItem)),
               ]);
 }
```

Comment: The !is_null shows $username is not null, but I got Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$table' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION). and the $query gave 502 Bad Gateway.

Comment: They are just placeholders.. you're only supposed to inject the scope function into your model.

Comment: I've put the scope in my model, then pass a variable to it. It works, the variable prints, but when I return it in the query it's null. How can it have value and be null at the same time?

Comment: it's not. You're not understanding how the query builder works. Let me update it for you.

Comment: I dont understand where to use $gallery = new Gallery(). In OctoberCMS, you drag and drop the Record List and choose your Scope function from the one in your Model. Then you pass a $type to the Scope, and inside the Scope you return the $query. Now the Record List is filtered by that Scope. I'm passing it from a Component.

Comment: Here is a diagram of what I'm trying to do. https://i.imgur.com/5R8gCI7.png

Comment: https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/components#external-property-values please read that.
Can you update your question with your component definition and your page definition? the parts before the html code.

Comment: I can get the scope to work by manually entering 'matt' as the query parameter, but it has to be dynamic and pulled from the URL into a variable. Here is the page http://pastebin.com/UtKq9dha.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136137/discussion-between-tschallacka-and-matt-mcmanis).